# Sending null data from $.post to controller model

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

My Model -

```
 public class Phasessfilter
{
    public string Searchterm {get;set;}
    public string ob1 {get;set;}
    public string ob2 {get;set;}
    public string ob3 {get;set;}
    public List<string> ob4 { get; set; }
    public List<string> ob5 { get; set; } 
}
```

Controller -

```
  public JsonResult GtRlts(Phasessfilter jop)
    {
    }
```

this is my script

```
    var recr = "";
    var study = "";
    var results = "";
    var phases1 = [];
    var fund = [];
  var values =  { Searchterm: Searchterm, ob1: recr, ob2: study, ob3: results, ob4: phases1, ob5: fund }

    $.post("GtRlts", values, function (abc) {

   }
```

So i am getting values for Searchterm , ob1 ,ob2 ,ob3 but i am getting null values for ob4 and ob5 .why is List not taking the array values or am i doing something wrong .
P.S - i dont want to use $.ajax

Comment: You have to set List as a parameters. List<Phasessfilter> jop

Answer (score 3):

Change your model to

```
public class Phasessfilter
{
    public string Searchterm {get;set;}
    public string ob1 {get;set;}
    public string ob2 {get;set;}
    public string ob3 {get;set;}
    public List<string> ob4 { get; set; }
    public List<string> ob5 { get; set; } 
    public Phasessfilter()
    {
        ob4 = new List<string>();
        ob5 = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Comment: @HimaanSingh i am trying it and i am getting count=0 not null. Do you miss something else?

Answer (score 2):

Hey the code written is absolutely fine you just need to test with the values in it and it works just fine.

here is sample Js code

```
 var searchterm = "test1";
    var recr = "test2";
    var study = "test3";
    var results = "test4";
    var phases1 = ["Test5","Test6"];
    var fund = ["Test6", "Test7"];
    debugger;
    var values = { Searchterm: searchterm, ob1: recr, ob2: study, ob3: results, ob4: phases1, ob5: fund }

    $.post(path + "/Dashboard/Home/GtRlts", values, function (abc) {

    });
```

and the output for a reference rest of the code is same.

[image]

Comment: send phases1 =[] and check it in debug ob4 is null or not in server.

Comment: Yes, it will, of course, come as a null as it is a good practice is to initialize all your list properties in a constructor as stated in the another answer. But it will not, either way, gona cause a problem while deserializing JSON object.so Precisely to avoid null we can define Phasessfilter as stated by you

Answer (score 0):

You have just **define array variable** so it get null value

```
var phases1 = [];
var fund = [];
```

You have to **add items** in it:

```
var phases1 = [1,2];
var fund = [3,4];
```